# Highcharts - column chart has space between bar and xAxis

Tags: highcharts

How can I prevent this space:
[image]
I try a lot but no success.
Here is my options:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    "chart": {
      "type": "column"
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "categories": ["1/1/2018", "2/1/2018", "3/1/2018"]
    },
    "legend": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "yAxis": {
      "categories": []
    },
    "series": [{
      "data": [1, 3, 1]
    }]
  });
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/f5JUU/76/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the empty category definition on the `yAxis` to make highchart automatically generate values for the yAxis:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  "chart": {
    "type": "column"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["1/1/2018", "2/1/2018", "3/1/2018"]
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "yAxis": {
  },
  "series": [{
    "data": [1, 3, 1]
  }]
});
```

**JSFiddle working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/sq1hf68r/

Comment: I have the same issue while repeatedly drilling down and drilling up the chart. Any suggestions?